# Split a string by single spaces

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
s = "alpha beta      gamma delta"
```

I'm trying to split this string with a single space as the delimiter without removing extra spaces to get this:

```
["alpha", "beta", "     gamma", "delta"]
```

Is there a way to do this?

The following does not give the results that I want:

```
s.split(" ") # => ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"]
s.split # => ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"]
```

Comment: Your logic is not clear. What is the reason your expected result is not `["alpha", "beta", "", "", "", "", "", "gamma", "delta"]`, or `["alpha", "beta   ", "  gamma", "delta"]`, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying a word boundary followed by one whitespace:

```
string = "alpha beta      gamma delta"
p string.split(/\b\s/)
# ["alpha", "beta", "     gamma", "delta"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.split(/(?<! ) /)
  #=> ["alpha", "beta", "     gamma", "delta"]
```

The regular expression matches each space that is not preceded by a space, `(?<! )` being a *negative lookbehind*.